# How to generate every [X,Y] possible for a given list?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to generate every combination possible given a list. I want every [X,Y] combination possible.
Here's an example :

```
?- arguments(A,[1,2,3]).  
A = [1,2] ; A = [1,3] ; A = [2,1] ; A = [2,3] ; A = [3,1] ;
A = [3,2]
```

I have tried multiple things, but I've yet to find a working one.
I am pretty sure the idea is to use prolog's ability to try every possibility as such :

```
element(X,[X|_],1).
element(X,[_|Q],N) :- element(X,Q,NewN), N is NewN + 1.
```

This predicate can return the element at the position N, or return the position of the element X, or generate every possibility. Exemple :

```
?- element(X,[a,b,c],N).  
N = 1
X = a 

N = 2
X = b

N = 3
X = c
```

Thanks for the help.

**Edit following gusbro answer :**
I can't use already existing predicates, it's part of a course.
Reading your answer, I came up with this :

```
remove_element_x(X, [X|Q], Q).
remove_element_x(X, [T|Q], [T|Res]) :- remove_element_x(X,Q,Res). 

arguments([X,Y],L) :-
    element(X,L,_),
    remove_element_x(X,L,L2),
    element(Y,L2,_).
```

remove_element_x/3 remove the element x from the list and returns the new list.
But the backtracking is not working :

```
?- arguments(A,[1,2,3]). 
A = [1,2] ? 
yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3) to select an element from a list (and get the remaining list), then do it again to select another element from the remaining list).

i.e.:

```
 arguments([A,B], L):-
   select(A, L, L1),
   select(B, L1,_).
```

Test case:

```
?- arguments(A,[1,2,3]).
A = [1, 2] ;
A = [1, 3] ;
A = [2, 1] ;
A = [2, 3] ;
A = [3, 1] ;
A = [3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I edited my post accordingly, please take a look

Comment: @Chuck: you can view the implementation of `select/3` by querying `listing(select/3).`